# How to read body of a POST request with GCDWebServerRequest

Tags: ios, xcode, gcdwebserver

I have the following handler to respond to POST request:

```
[_webServer addHandlerForMethod:@"POST"
                           path:@"/"
                   requestClass:[GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest class]
                   processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerRequest* request) {

                       NSString* value = [[(GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest*)request arguments] objectForKey:@"value"];
                       NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><p>%@</p></body></html>", value];
                       return [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithHTML:html];

                   }];
```

When the handler is triggered, `NSString* value` keeps giving me null. I am able to debug and view the `GCDWebServerRequest` object (screenshot).

[image]

There is a field `_data` which I wish to obtain.

May I know how to go about it?

Here is my POST request for reference:

```
 var request = require('request');
 request({
    url: 'http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080',
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: "12345678"
 }, function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body);
 });
```

I am using `npm request` to run the POST request. If I did `value=test` for my POST request, it gives me this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For NPM `request`, if you wish to use content-type of `x-www-form-urlencoded`, you will have to call the parameter `form` instead of `body`.

Example:

```
request.post('http://service.com/upload', {form:{key:'value'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GCDWebServer code is correct but the POST request you generate is not. The body must contain data formatted as a URL encoded form e.g. `value=test`.

Comment: I am developing for both android and iOS. The post request works for android though. I tried changing to `value=test` but it is giving me syntax error. I have edited my post on this

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `GCDWebServerRequest` and `override func write(_ data: Data)` to access the body (e.g. for debugging this kind of issue). Just set `requestClass` to `MyCustomPostRequest.self` in `addHandlerForMethod`.